# How to change between text and icon using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code with some dropdown selection. I want to change the text contained inside a span with an icon.

I have a more complex code in the background, that allows me to dynamically change the values of a certain number of divs specified by the user, so I will post here just the part of code that I think will be useful for you to help me with this.

```
$("select.heating-type-select").on("change", function () {
    $("." + target + " span.heating-type-room").html($(this).val());                
});
```

So, to explain the code, I have undefined number of divs created every time, and for every div I create also a row with some options, like for example the one in the code.

Are there any way to add at the bottom of my code an if statement that says (is not a code but just the logic)

I have my value `($(this).val())`, before replace the text with this value I want to check

```
if(previousvalue == something) {
    replace previousvalue with html tag) and than add this to the html
}
else just add the value that i have since early
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you provide sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: here you are, is enabled only the add room button.
http://jsfiddle.net/9AQrr/2/

Comment: you can save previous value to select attr and check it on change event